# How can there be multiple wallets from the same Ethereum private key?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

So I'm interested in storing some ERC-20 tokens in 100 different wallets as an experiment and would like to know what the easiest way to do this would be without having to manually store 100 different private keys. Also, I know the ledger does something similar where a single private key lets you use wallets for different blockchains, what is the science behind this?

Additionally, if I were to program a smart contract to send the tokens to the list of 100 addresses, would that help me save on gas compared to if I just send the 100 transactions from a normal wallet?

Thank you so very much.

Comment: there can't be multiple wallets from the same private key, you got something wrong.

Comment: if the contracts of the tokens you are going to send support `BatchSend` method, this is the one you have to use to save gas. Otherwise, every new transaction will use 20,000 gasd units, thats the overhead for sending the tx.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is a [hierarchially deterministic address generation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33395/what-is-a-hd-wallet-for-ether-and-how-to-create-one-using-nodejs) from a single seed. Here is a [HD wallet JavaScript package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereum-hdwallet) for Ethereum.

There are also tools [for token bulk sending](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33395/what-is-a-hd-wallet-for-ether-and-how-to-create-one-using-nodejs) that have minor transaction cost savings over doing a single naive transaction per recipient.